# How to get a "reverse exponential distribution"?

Tags: netlogo, distribution, exponential, exponential-distribution

Suppose I have X patches, and patches have a patch variable called "patch-quality", with values between 0 and 1. I want this patch variable to be generated randomly, but in two different ways (two different scenarios):

- Scenario 1: random number between 0 and 1 but with most patches with patch-quality close to 0.
- Scenario 2: random number between 0 and 1 but most patches with patch-quality close to 1.

For Scenario 1 I don't have a problem, I use an exponential distribution with a mean of 0.13.

> if (patch-quality-distribution = "scenario-1") [set patch-quality
> random-exponential 0.13]

My problem is with Scenario 2. I want an exponential distribution like the one with scenario 1 but "in reverse". Is there a way to have a sort of reverse exponential distribution in NetLogo where most patches have a patch-quality close to 1?

Comment: Maybe something like `[set patch-quality (1 - random-exponential mean_value]` could work for you?

Comment: @Pol I second this. It is pretty much the answer so I suggest you write it down as an answer instead of a comment

Comment: You're asking for a reversed distribution, not an inverse. @Pol's comment is the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For getting that reverse exponential distribution (not inverse, as @pjs pointed out in his comment), you can use:

`[set patch-quality (1 - random-exponential mean_value)]`

Comment: Thank you very much!! this answers my question :) (also thanks LeirsW and pjs for the corrections)